# Restoring variable from ckpt file saved with variable_scope

Tags: tensorflow

The variable has been generated using `variable_scope`

```py
 with tf.variable_scope('conv1') as scope:
    kernel = _variable_with_weight_decay('weights',
                                         shape=[5, 5, 3, 64],
                                         stddev=5e-2,
                                         wd=0.0)
    conv = tf.nn.conv2d(images, kernel, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
    biases = _variable_on_cpu('biases', [64], tf.constant_initializer(0.0))
    bias = tf.nn.bias_add(conv, biases)
    conv1 = tf.nn.relu(bias, name=scope.name)
    _activation_summary(conv1)
```

And then the variables have been saved and restored using the ckpt file. However, after restoring the attempt to get the variable back with the following code fails.

```py
with tf.variable_scope('conv1'):
    sasa=tf.get_variable("kernel")
```

The network (and the above conv1 layer) comes from the CIFAR10 example:
https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/tutorials/deep_cnn/index.html https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10

**EDIT 1:**

'kernel' does not work but 'biases' does work.

```py
with tf.variable_scope('conv1'):
    sasa=tf.get_variable("biases")
```

Comment: I think scope works only for adding to graph. Use `tf.get_variable('conv1/kernel')`. The easiest way (I know) to find correct variable name is to load graph in tensorboard, find corresponding node and then find variable name.

Comment: Cheers, but I checked and it should be just tf.get_variable("biases")

Comment: Shouldn't it be `tf.get_variable('weights')` instead of `tf.get_variable('kernel')`?

Comment: Yes, that's it! Please put it as an asnwer and I'll accept it.